# CTE to pull entire tree from arbitrary entry

Tags: sql-server, tree, sql-server-2012, common-table-expression

I'm trying to build a CTE which will pull back all records which are related to a given, *arbitrary* record in the database.

```
Create table Requests (
  Id bigint,
  OriginalId bigint NULL,
  FollowupId bigint NULL
)

insert into Requests VALUES (1, null, 3)
insert into Requests VALUES (2, 1, 8)
insert into Requests VALUES (3, 1, 4)
insert into Requests VALUES (4, 3, null)
insert into Requests VALUES (5, null, null)
insert into Requests VALUES (6, null, 7)
insert into Requests VALUES (7, 6, null)
insert into Requests VALUES (8, 2, null)
```

`OriginalId` is always the `Id` of a previous record (or `null`).  `FollowupId` points to the most recent followup record (which, in turn, points back via `OriginalId`) and can probably be ignored, but it's there if it's helpful.

I can easily pull back either all ancestors or all descendants of a given record using the following CTE

```
;With TransactionList (Id, originalId, followupId, Steps)
AS
(
    Select Id, originalId, followupId, 0 as Steps from requests where Id = @startId
    union all
    select reqs.Id, reqs.originalId, reqs.followupId, Steps + 1 from requests reqs
    inner join TransactionList tl on tl.Id = reqs.originalId --or tl.originalId = reqs.Id
)
SELECT Id from TransactionList
```

However, if I use both where clauses, I run into recursion, hit the recursion limit, and it bombs out.  Even combining both sets, I don't get the entire tree - just one branch from it.

I don't care about anything other than the list of Ids.  They don't need to be sorted, or to display their relationship or anything.  Doesn't hurt, but not necessary. But I need every `Id` in a given tree to pull back the same list when it's passed as `@startId`.

As an example of what I'd like to see, this is what the output should be when `@startId` is set to any value 1-4 or 8:

```
1
2
3
4
8
```

And for either 6 or 7, I get back both 6 and 7.

Comment: You aren't new around here. How about some ddl and sample data? sqlfiddle.com perhaps?

Comment: @SeanLange - I couldn't get the fiddle to run my CTE. But I've added data and expected results to the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just create 2 CTE's.

The first CTE will get the Root of the hierarchy, and the second will use the Root ID to get the descendants of the Root.

```
;WITH cteRoot AS (
    SELECT  *, 0 [Level]
    FROM    Requests
    WHERE   Id = @startId
    UNION ALL
    SELECT  r.*, [Level] + 1
    FROM    Requests r
            JOIN cteRoot cte ON r.Id = cte.OriginalID
),
cteDesc AS (
    SELECT  *
    FROM    cteRoot
    WHERE   OriginalId IS NULL
    UNION ALL
    SELECT  r.*, [Level] + 1
    FROM    Requests r
            JOIN cteDesc cte ON r.OriginalId = cte.Id  
)
SELECT * FROM cteDesc
```

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/3bfa2/2)

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear enough in my initial version of the question. Combining the two just gives me a single branch of the tree top to bottom, but I need all branches.

Comment: @Bobson  I updated the query to just get the root and go down the hierarchy from there.

Comment: Perfect.  Thanks!  It seems so obvious in retrospect.